# How to store 2 digit integer value and float values in char array in C

Tags: c

Following is my C code to print values of char but I am getting unexpected results. The code is

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{

  char sendBuffer[1000];
  float count;
  int i;
  for(count=1.5;count<=2.5;)
  {
   for(i=0;i<=15;)
   {
     sendBuffer[0]=count+48;
     sendBuffer[1]='a';
     sendBuffer[2]='b';
     sendBuffer[3]='c';
     sendBuffer[4]=i+48;
     sendBuffer[5]='\0';
     printf("%s\n",sendBuffer);
     i=i+5;
    }
   count=count+0.5;
  }
}
```

The results I am getting are:

```
1abc0
1abc5
1abc:
1abc?
2abc0
2abc5
2abc:
2abc?
2abc0
2abc5
2abc:
2abc?
```

whereas, I was expecting something like

```
1.5abc0
1.5abc5
1.5abc10
1.5abc15
```

and so on. Can anybody tell me how to store integer and float values in char array in C?

Comment: You mean in a string, not in char. char is one byte.

Comment: but i have declared char array as 1000

Comment: Yes char array, not char. That's what I mean.

Comment: a char is a character of the string, a char array is a string.

Comment: @nouney i have edited my question, can you provide any solution of it?

Comment: Your algo is totally wrong for C. You're converting from float to char. This will round your float, and also might overflow the char for numbers bigger than 128. You need to convert the float to a string (a char array, and not a char) and concatenate (use strcat).

Comment: Here's a couple of hints: sendBuffer[0] is a single byte value, so it couldn't possibly represent 1.5.  Also, when you take a float like count and add it to 48, it gets cast to an integer, making it 1 or 2 depending on the loop location.

Comment: What about using ``sprintf`` ?

Comment: You are mixing apple and banana. You are missing some fundamental C notion. You should read some C book. There is plenty of free book, you just have to google for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can work:

```
snprintf(sendbuf, sizeof(sendbuf), "%.1fabc%d", count, i);
```

Comment: I think you have to use "%.1f" in order to get 3 chars

Comment: @user227666 it would help if you specify where you put this in your code.

Comment: @m0skit0 I did snprintf(sendBuffer, sizeof(sendBuffer), "%.1fabc%d", count, i); but it's showing no output

Comment: @user227666 Well I guess you tried it before saying it's not working. Just post the whole code you tried with this solution.

Comment: @user227666, ay ay ay :P

Answer (score 8):

I see the answers you're getting answer the problem, but don't give an explanation, and from the looks of it, you could use a good explanation, so here's what's happening:

#### Types in C

You need to understand that different types (`int`, `char`, `float`, `double`) take up different sizes in memory.  In C, a `char` is always considered to take up a single byte, and is in the range of -127 to 128.  (`unsigned char` goes from 0 to 255.)  `int`s take up 4 bytes, and their range is from -2M to 2M - 1.  `float` and `double` take 4 and 8 bytes respectively, and have a huge range, but limited precision.  (For more information, just search for "c type ranges", and you'll find lots of information, including these links on Stack Overflow, which also give you good explanations: [Definition of range of a data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944224/definition-of-range-of-a-data-type), [Guarantateed minimum size/range of C data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815180/guarantateed-minimum-size-range-of-c-data-types)).

Also, you know enough ascii to know to add 48 to a digit to get the char version, but make sure you have an ascii table nearby.  Conveniently, you can find one at http://www.asciitable.com.

You also have to understand that the compiler will do its best to convert from one to another, though in some cases, such as casting a `float` to an `int`, if you don't do it explicitly, your compiler should at least issue a warning.

Strings don't exist as a type in C.  Instead, you print into an array.  Other answers tell you how to do that.  What their code is doing is printing the values you want into a character array, which is all you need.

#### What your code is doing

Now, let's see what your current code is doing:

First of all, a quick sidebar: when you're doing a `for` loop, it's best to put the increment in the loop itself, so:

```
for(count=1.5;count<=2.5;count=count+0.5)
{
  for(i=0;i<=15;i=i+5)
```

would be more standardized.

Now, your first line is `sendBuffer[0]=count+48;`.  Here's what happens:

1. You're taking count, which starts at 1.5, and adding 48, so the first number is 49.5.
2. The compiler will automatically change a `float` to an `int`, though it should give you a warning about it.  It does so by truncating the value, changing 49.5 to 45.
3. It then changes `(int)49` to `(char)49` which is the same value, but takes up one byte instead of 4.  Ascii 49 is '1', so this happens to be the number you wanted.
4. The compiler does *not* do anything with the rest of the float.  It never sets sendBuffer[1] or [2] for this value.

Your next 3 lines hard code the second, third and fourth characters of the string to `abc`.  Even if your first line had set the full float value into `sendBuffer`, this would overwrite it.

Your final line takes i, which will be 0, 5, 10 and 15, and adds it to 48.  This is just like the first step, without the truncation from `float`.  So first it looks up ascii 48, which is '0', then ascii 53, which is '5'.  When `i` is 10, it now takes the int 58 and converts it to a character (again, changing it from 4 bytes to 1 byte).  Printing ascii 58 results in ':', and printing ascii 63 results in '?'.  And that's how your output ended up the way it did.

#### Possible solutions

Finally, a few words on the solution you were given:

Since all you're doing is outputting the result, you don't need `sendBuffer` nor `snprintf`.  Simply using

```
printf("%.1fabc%d\n", count, i);
```

would have sufficed.

It's instructive to think about what the printf family of functions does, though.  Though it's less efficient, let's use a few `snprintf`s to see what it's doing:

```
int index = 0;
index = snprintf(&sendbuf[index], sizeof(sendbuf) - index, "%.1f", count);
index += snprintf(&sendbuf[index], sizeof(sendbuf) - index, "abc");
index += snprintf(&sendbuf[index], sizeof(sendbuf) - index, "%d", i);
sendbuf[index++] = '\n';
sendbuf[index] = '\0';
```

What this does is what `*printf` does when you pass it multiple arguments: keep track of how much you've written and use that to tell where you're writing the next parts.

If you don't know it, the `a += b` syntax is shorthand for `a = a + b`.  `a++` means "give me the value of a, then increment it."

So the second line of my code will print out the float value into sendbuf, starting at the 0 position.  `*printf` always returns the number of characters printed, so in this example, it will always print 3 characters, and I set `index` to 3.

The next line writes the string abc into sendbuf, starting at position 3, and the line after that prints the value of `i` into position 6.  Finally, I add the \n for the new line, and the last line is the null terminator.  I don't put `index++` because I don't care about index any more, so don't need to bother incrementing it.  I put `\0` (as did you above) instead of 0, simply because `\0` reminds the programmer that we're dealing with a char array, not an integer array.

Again, all these lines aren't necessary, but since some of the issue seemed to be understanding what `printf` does, I thought it would be helpful.

Comment: +1, Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; show him how to catch fish, and you feed him for a lifetime. :P

Comment: Some people advise here on SO not to write unnecessarily long answers, I respectfully disagree, The answers should not just answer *How one should do it?* but also *why one should do it?* This proves to be really helpful to new members as well as other googlers .... But unfortunately, here people who answer quick but small get upvotes more than the guy who has put hard work to make a nice answer ( this may not be true always but in most cases )... In my opinion you get a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a byte to the output array.  The first element needs 3 characters (bytes) not one.

```
sprintf(sendBuffer,"%0.1f",count);
sendBuffer[3] = 'a';
....
```

Comment: I think you have to use `"%.1f"` in order to get 3 chars

Comment: @user227666 `.1f%` is wrong, code provided by Jim and mohit works fine: http://ideone.com/FnyLGU

Comment: @DavidRF i told you in previous comment that it's working now